# pronouncing -ó in poetry

Tags: pronunciation, poetry, diacritics

Do you guys know how '**-ó**' is pronounced?

Context: [The Windhover](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44402/the-windhover), Hopkins.

> No wonder of it: shéer **plód** makes plough down sillion
>   Shine, and blue-bleak embers, ah my dear,
>         Fall, gall themselves, and gash gold-vermilion."

Comment: +1 for asking a perfectly reasonable question.  There was no justification for this being downvoted.

Comment: Perhaps the search mechanism needs improvement. If an answer falls in the forest and no one can find it, what does it duplicate, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Hopkins wrote his poems to be read in [sprung rhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprung_rhythm), as opposed to the repetitive patterns expected by the readers of his day. He used the accent marks to indicate where he wanted the emphasis to be placed.

Emphasis does not change the pronunciation of a simple one-syllable word.  However, in a longer and more complex word, it can change the way the word is said.